# WHat is the best identifier of a DIV or other element?

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a div or any other element. I need to keep some parameter in it like a number (ID of the record) or something and I need to manipulate (change it) with ajax using jquery.

I can use the div ID or class, but I don't think this is a good idea to keep it for variables. Is there any other html attribute that is not in use and is semantically right to use for this purpose. I was thinking of using a NAME attribute, would this be good to manipulate it using jquery?

I could have some empty 12 that is hiiden but I don't think of having the value of this div to be used as a variable a good idea.

What is a good idea to use as a variable in HTML elements?

Comment: For the record, `name` attribute is valid only in form elements.

Comment: Yes, thanx. I just took a look and see that's the case yes.

Comment: No problem.. if you want to stick with data associated directly "in" the element, use fudgey answer, if you prefer to separate the data from the elements feel free to implement my suggestion. :)

Comment: Yes that is the problem on stackoverflow, I can accept only one answer although both are good and accepatable :-(

Comment: accept the answer you're really using and upvote the other(s) - good enough for everyone. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the object's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

---

jQuery automatically populates the element's data from the HTML5 `data-*` attribute. So add your data like this:

```
<div id="someID" data-option1="selection1"></div>
```

you can get the data from the object like this:

```
var opt = $('#someID').data().option1; // opt = "selection1"
```

or

```
var opt = $('#someID').data('option1'); // opt = "selection1"
```

Comment: data() seems what I am looking for, thanx. But it has a missing feature. I can not set it using server side when page is first generated because it is jquery only, not a HTML.

Comment: Thanx, that would solve my problem, yes. How will the data-option1 pass validation?

Comment: It should pass validation if the validator supports HTML5

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate in the server side code associative JS array that will "map" each `div` to the data using its existing `id`, then use that array instead of attributes of the element itself.

The final array can look like this:

```
var _data = { "div1": "first data", "div2": "second data", "div3": "third data" }
```

And to use it, something like:

```
var id = element.id; //or element.attr("id") if jQuery object
var data = _data[id];
...
```